# Was SourceToHTMLConverter.class removed from java 7?

Tags: java

Attempting to build some javadocs using the com.sun.tools.doclets. Existing code is referencing a class file

```
SourceToHTMLConverter.class
```

Found it in an older JRE

```
JRE\160_38\lib\tools.jar\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\util\
```

However all of the JRE7 that I have does not seem to contain this class. Does anyone know why?

Comment: That's what happens when you depend on Oracle specific internal code... Don't do it, we keep saying.

Comment: Okay... Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class isn't part of Java's public API.  It's no longer part of the Java distribution.  In general it's a very bad idea to rely on anything in the package `com.sun`, especially if it also includes `internal` in the package name.  This is because they're not part of the public, documented API, and the developers make absolutely no promises about how much these classes will change from version to version.

If you rely on such classes, your code isn't guaranteed to be portable from one JVM to another (it may or may not run on IBM's JMV or on Android), or ever from one version to the next of the *same* JVM.  They don't even promise not to change these out from under you between minor revisions.

As for your question about why it was removed: because they didn't feel the need to keep it anymore, so they got rid of it.  Simple as that.

Don't use those classes.  Stick to the public, documented API.

Comment: Furthermore, the compiler emits a warning if you use such classes.  Always enable all compiler warnings, never suppress them, and pay attention to what they're telling you.